# MonoTouch application build

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, installation, ios-simulator, monodevelop

I have managed to install the trial version of MonoTouch as I am interested in buying a license but I want to try the product first. The problem that I am having is this:

1. I have installed MonoTouch and MonoDevelop
2. I have downloaded Xcode which has the iphone sdk's bundled in.

When I open monodevelop and create a new iPhone application or project, it creates it and opens it in monodevelop. Awesome. when I try to compile and run in the simulator, I get an error stating "The iphone sdk is not installed."

Now, it could be due to the fact that the xcode I downloaded from the apple developer site is an app file ie no installation is required, you extract the dmg file and then Xcode runs straight from there and you can copy it from the dmg straight to your drive and run it from there. is there any specific place where I should put that file for monotouch to find it? how can I solve this?

Another problem, upon opening the xib file in my project, it does not open interface builder in monodevelop, it opens the files source code. hopefully by solving the xcode issue it will take care of this as well?

Using a Macbook Pro OSX 10.7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the problem is that MonoDevelop can't find Xcode.

The easiest way is to install Xcode from the AppStore. In this case MonoDevelop will detect the location automatically.

You can also tell MonoDevelop where the SDK is in MonoDevelop's preferences (remember to restart MonoDevelop):

[image]

Or you can copy Xcode.app into your Applications directory, and MonoDevelop will find it automatically (if you have the latest MonoDevelop version and Xcode 4.3).

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thanks for your help. I downloaded another version of xcode which physically installed it on the machine now everything works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running XCode and checked that it is installed? Might seem like a silly question, but when you download XCode from appstore you only download the installation program, which you in turn need to run to actually install XCode.

Comment: Hi Arne, Valid question indeed. that is exactly it, xcode does not "install", I downloaded it from apples developer website. A DMG file was downloaded, when double clicking the dmg file it opens up and inside of it is an xcode icon (the app), no installer package, just the app, i can open that app straight from the dmg and xcode runs and i can create new projects an compile and run them within xcode no problem. yet it does not install on the machine it self and i think that is part of, if not all of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I downloaded another version of xcode which physically installed it on the machine now everything works beautifully.